# Java Disposing JFrame window from another class

Tags: java, swing

A class Main has main method in which JFrame is constructed.
And class MainView has panels and buttons which are appended on the JFrame.

What I need to do is disposing JFrame window by clicking a certain button.

I have tried various ways which I have found from here, Stackoverflow. But no solution so far.

```
public final class Main {

static JFrame frame = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                frame = new MainView("Blackjack 2017");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(650, 450);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });


}
}
```

From

```
public class MainView extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4728244239185625080L;
private Dealer dealer;
private User user;
private ControlPanel controlPanel;
public static Container c;

public MainView() {

}

public MainView(String title) throws IOException {

    super(title);

    dealer = new Dealer();
    user = new User();

    System.out.println(title + " frame made");

    controlPanel = new ControlPanel();
    controlPanel.setControlPanel();

    c = getContentPane();
    c.add(controlPanel);

    controlPanel.getPlayBtn().addActionListener(this);
    controlPanel.getExitBtn().addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Play")) {
        System.out.println("play clicked");
        c.removeAll();
        c.add(playPanel);
        c.validate();

    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {


    }
```

Comment: *"The point is how to access to the JFrame fame from another class, even though I set the frame static"* - You don't need to, `MainView` is already the  main frame on the screen, simply call `dispose` to close it. Don't rely on `static` as a cross communication mechanism, it's not what it's really there for. There are other, better ways to achieve the same result which cause less issues

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for some basics about closing a frame (or dialog).

You can just use The `ExitAction` class, which is a generic `Action` that can be added to any button (or menu item) and will act as if the user clicked on the close button of the window.

The code works by dispatching a `windowClosing` event to the window. So it assumes you have invoked the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` for the window.

Comment: The point is how to access to the JFrame fame from another class, even though I set the frame static.

Comment: @HyunJung Well your class extends frame so there is no need for a static variable. Trying to use a static variable indicates poor design. Extending JFrame is also not a good design. In any case, I showed you a generic solution on how to access the frame whether the frame is in the same class or a different class, without using static variables. If you don't want to use the `ExitAction`, then look at the code to see it finds the current frame.